# How do I transfer a value from area to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom-events

How do I transfer the value of `i` into the function `dispCar()`
I am trying to pick the object out of array using the index value which the value of `i` represents.

```
var cars = document.getElementById("carList");
var car = cars.querySelectorAll("li");

for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {

    car[i].addEventListener("mouseover", dispCar); 

}


function dispCar() {

    var carStats = [ 
    {Mfg: "Cadillac", Model: "CTS", Year: "2016", Horsepower: "600+hp", color: "White"}, 
    {Mfg: "Buick", Model: "LaCrosse", Year: "2016", Horsepower: "310hp", color: "Champagn Silver Metalic"},
    {Mfg: "Chevrolet", Model: "Camaro", Year: "2016", Horsepower: "475hp", color: "White"}
]


    document.getElementById("display").className = "display";
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = carStats[0].Mfg;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`addEventListener` takes in a function as its second argument. You can just pass a function that calls `dispCar` like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
    car[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        dispCar(i);
    });
}
```

You can still access `i` from `addEventListener` because of [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

See the [`EventTarget.addEventListener` Documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up your for loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {

  car[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function dispCar() {

    var carStats = [ 
      {Mfg: "Cadillac", Model: "CTS", Year: "2016", Horsepower: "600+hp", color: "White"}, 
      {Mfg: "Buick", Model: "LaCrosse", Year: "2016", Horsepower: "310hp", color: "Champagn Silver Metalic"},
      {Mfg: "Chevrolet", Model: "Camaro", Year: "2016", Horsepower: "475hp", color: "White"}
    ]

    document.getElementById("display").className = "display";
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = carStats[0].Mfg;
  }

}
```

Comment: It still doesn't work because when I use the code below and I pass "i" in dispCar(i). What I am passing is an object called MouseEvent not the value of "i".

Comment: It still doesn't work because when I use the code below and I pass "i" in dispCar(i). What I am passing is an object called MouseEvent not the value of "i".

    var cars = document.getElementById("carList");
    var car = cars.querySelectorAll("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < car.length; i++) {
      car[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function dispCar(i) {
   console.log(i);
           var carStats = [ 
          {Mfg: "Cadillac", Model: "CTS", Year: "2016", Horsepower: "600+hp", color: "White"}, 
    ]
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = carStats[i].Mfg;
         });
    }